# My kernel dies when I fit my LightFm model from Microsoft Recommenders

Tags: jupyter-notebook, kernel, recommendation-engine, lightfm

I downloaded the code to run it in my Jupyter Notebook

https://github.com/microsoft/recommenders/blob/main/examples/02_model_hybrid/lightfm_deep_dive.ipynb

When I try to run the LightFm model the kernel dies (On the exact same code from the link)

This happens specifically at batch [10] when I try to fit the model

model1.fit(interactions=train_interactions,
epochs=NO_EPOCHS);

I tried making a totally new virtual environment, a test kernel installing modules from scratch that didn't work either

I tried it on 2 different pc's it didn't work

I installed that latest pip , packages etc

I saw some YT videos like installing freetype and other fixes but these were general for kernels dying and didn't help

I tried editing it and making it less power consuming both on my model and the microsoft one writing using less threads and verbose(I also tried without threads and all
the combinations etc) but nothing worked.
model1.fit(interactions=train_interactions, epochs=NO_EPOCHS, num_threads=2, verbose=False)

Could you try downloading and running the code and see if you can fix it?

My specs are: Intel core i5 -4460, Nvidia GTX 1060 and 32 GB's of RAM

Thank you!

I tried to fit the LightFm model and expected to work but the kernel dies everytime